# Retrieving huge data in python to file - out of memory

Tags: python, out-of-memory, buffer

Let's imagine that we download a huge data from the Internet using python code. And we are not able to fit it in memory.

Are there exists some solution in python to download to some buffer (of fixed size, let say `1 MB`) and flush to file on disk in case of overfilling ?

Generally, how to resolve it in python ?

When it comes to exact use case I mean retrieving data from database using existing client for python. The aim for data is file.

Comment: From where would these data come from ? Typically, from a database, libraries allow you to get the data by chunks. For more information you should precise your question !

Comment: Sorry for unclear information. It is about ElastiSearch. (I though that this problem is more general).

Comment: The `elasticsearch` library quite surely has a way to get chunks of data. And so do most of modules based on big data ! If this does not answer your question, I would recommend you to ask your question again w/ pieces of code and a clearer question =)